# Render form element in view added to form from controller

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

How can we render form element in **view** which is added dynamically from **Controller**?

Comment: Did you read the [form view helpers documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html)?

Comment: What did you tried  so far ? Before asking did you performed any search on the web ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i think that you wants a thing like this

in your controller:

```
use Publicacion\Form\AlbumForm; 
use Zend\Form\Element;

class ControllerAlbum extends AbstractActionController 
{

    // example action
    public function addAction(){
        $album=new Album();
        $form=new AlbumForm();

        // create element username
        $username = new Element\Text('username');

        $username
            ->setLabel('Username')
            ->setAttributes(array('class' => 'username','size'  => '30',
            ));

        // create element password
        $password = new Element\Password('password');
        $password
            ->setLabel('Password')
            ->setAttributes(array('size'  => '30',
            ));

        $form->add($username);
        $form->add($password);

        $form->bind($album);

        $request=$this->request->getRequest();
        if($request->isPost()){
            //... doing anything
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
        }
        return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
    }
}
```

the class album form:

//example class

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class AlbumForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
     {
         // we want to ignore the name passed
         parent::__construct('album');

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'id',
             'type' => 'Hidden',
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'title',
             'type' => 'Text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Title',
             ),
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'artist',
             'type' => 'Text',
             'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Artist',
             ),
         ));
         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'submit',
             'type' => 'Submit',
             'attributes' => array(
                 'value' => 'Go',
                 'id' => 'submitbutton',
             ),
         ));
    }
}
```

And the view add.phtml

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('post', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('username'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('password'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('send'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Hi @Darwin , this is what exactly I want but My controller is a ajax request and instead of returning viewModel it will return JsonModel. Otherwise everythings are similiar .  How can I get the form element created in controller when it returns JsonModel?

Comment: Yogendra, I found this on the web , did not try it but it is very similar to the previous example , you just have to try to add the elements . I could not even try. I hope it helps you: http://hantsy.blogspot.com.uy/2013/11/create-restful-application-with_19.html